# Can I store credit card data in SQL Server encrypted locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, encryption

I have a C# application running on local server which is inside firewall. Only the employees (4-6) have access to application. Payments not done through application payments are processed online via bank app.

Now case is: customer gives their credit card detail over phone for payments and we need to do payments in 2 or more installments, so is it okay to store this information (including cc no. or may be cvv as well) in SQL Server installed on a local server, or should we make hard copy of data or just ask data again from user?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please read & follow the instructions of [PCI-DSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard), Payment Card Industry - Data Security Standard . In short, you might not want to involve this process, as it's quite complicated.

Comment: What you want to do is likely illegal, from what you said, the way you are handling things is not PCI compliant.

Comment: If your company is `PCI Compliant` then you can. but looks like you are not.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping, yes i read that so complicated for me and yes our company is not PCI compliant. Is their any way we can make it working or we should make payments on phone?

Comment: Your best bet is to use a 3rd party payment gateway, there are plenty out there, many of which handle re-billing and instalment payments.

Comment: alright thanks, will look for these..